# Sencha Touch (Ext.device.push) for GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)

Tags: sencha-touch, google-cloud-messaging

(How) can I use Sencha Touch's 2.2alpha `Ext.device.push` for GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)?

What are other possible other solutions for adding Push Notifications to a Sencha Touch WebApp packaged by the Sencha CMD Tools?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter.

They have PUB  SUB clients which you can use.